# My laptop display is just a black screen

Tags: 11.10, graphics, display

the external display works fine but my main display is just black i know it works beacuse it works fine in windows but it wont work in linux D: my laptop is a acer-aspire 5734z ive tryed reinstalling ubuntu and it still dosent work. help???

Answer (score 1):

There's a kernel bug that affects Acer laptops. Basically, the backlight isn't being turned on. You can read the [bug report here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/881166).

The bug hasn't been fixed, but there's a workaround:

In short, the answer that worked for me was two-fold: first, place the following in `/etc/rc.local`:

```
setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=0
```

That should make the backlight turn on. You can run the command from the command line to test it, but from the command line, be sure to put `sudo` in front.

Then, if the backlight doesn't come on after the computer goes into power-saving mode, put the command into root's crontab. Run `sudo crontab -eu root` and insert the following line:

```
*/1 * * * /usr/bin/setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=0
```

This will cause the backlight to turn on no more than one minute after the computer resumes.